# Why access violation do not appear?

Tags: factorial

Why access violation do not appear in runtime when calculating factorial of 100007 ?

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

long fact_value[100001] ; 
long fact(long n);

int main() {     
  fact_value[0] = 1;     
  fact_value[1] = 1;   
  int T;     
  int num;    
  scanf("%d",&T);     
  for(int i=0;i<T;i++) {     
    scanf("%d",&num);    
    printf("%ld\n",fact(num));  
  }          
  return 0;
}

long fact(long n) {  
  if(fact_value[n]!=0) 
    return fact_value[n];
  return fact_value[n] = (n*fact(n-1))%1000000007;
}
```

> This program is dynamic approach to solve factorial of numbers with recursion

Comment: Could you be more specific about what your problem is with that code? Is there an access violation happaning? Please edit your question.

Comment: Is this C or C++?  Tag with the appropriate language.